# Identifying isNull and isNotNul in dataframe

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to identify the columns which are null and which are not null and depending on that trying to insert a string.

```
ab_final = join_df.withColumn("linked_A_B", 
           when(
              col("a3_inbound").isNull() & ("a3_item").isNull()
           ), 'No Value'
           ).when(
              (col("it_item").isNull() & ("it_export").isNull()),
              'NoShipment'
           ).when(
              (col("a3_inbound").isNotNull() & ("it_export").isNotNull()),
              'Export')
           )
```

I'm getting the below error
str' object has no attribute 'isnull'

Plz help

Comment: Looks like `("it_export")` should be `col("it_export")`.

Comment: @Florian is right, but the same is valid to `("a3_item")`

Comment: @Florian &  André Pacheco, the above solution works